# How to validate response object in Spring WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using ***Springs' Webclient*** to make a **HTTP GET** call.

How can I validate the response object `GetPersonBasicInfoResWrapper`'s property that I received as a response of my HTTP call.

I am trying to validate the `birthDate` inside the `flatMap` by blocking the response object, but it doesn't look like the most functional way of doing it.

Following is the excerpt from my code.

```
private Mono<GetPersonBasicInfoResWrapper> getPersonBasicInfo(Double personId, LocalDate birthDate,
            CallerRequestMetaData callerInfo) {
        return middlewareWebClient
                .get()
                .uri(...)
                ...
                ...
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(client -> {
                    GetPersonBasicInfoResWrapper block = client.bodyToMono(GetPersonBasicInfoResWrapper.class).block();
                    
                    LocalDate personBirthDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(block.getBirthDate().toInstant(),ZoneId.of(Constants.DEFAULT_TIME_ZOME)).toLocalDate();
                    
                    if (!personBirthDate.equals(birthDate))
                        throw new YakeenRowadException(Errors.INCORRECT_ID_BIRTH_DATE_G, birthDate.toString()); 
                    else
                        return client.bodyToMono(GetPersonBasicInfoResWrapper.class);
                });
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: dont `block()` in the code, you loose all purpose of using webflux if you block. First return a `Mono<GetPersonBasicInfoResWrapper>` then validate, by calling `Mono<GetPersonBasicInfoResWrapper>#flatMap`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Exactly! I dont want to block either but i am not sure how to implement the validation in a non-blocking way. can you post some code please.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
private Mono<PersonInfo> getPersonInfo(Double personId) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(...)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> {
                return response.bodyToMono(PersonInfo.class);
            });
}

private LocalDate toLocalDate(Instant instant) {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of(Constants.DEFAULT_TIME_ZOME))
                        .toLocalDate();
}

public Mono<PersonInfo> doSomething(Double personId, LocalDate birthDate) {
    return getPersonInfo(personId)
             .flatMap(personInfo -> {
                final LocalDate birthDate = toLocalDate(personInfo.getBirthDate().toInstant());
                if (!personBirthDate.equals(birthDate)) { 
                    return Mono.error(new YakeenRowadException(Errors.INCORRECT_ID_BIRTH_DATE_G, birthDate.toString()));
                }
                return Mono.just(personInfo);
            });
}
```

Don't validate during the fetch, validation is business logic, and should be in the layer above.

1. you fetch and return
2. you validate.
3. If validation fails, you return a Mono.error() to the calling client.

I have no idea what "MetaData" was supposed to be. I hope it's not the url, because passing it that way is wrong.

(try to avoid verbose naming)

Comment: This looks helpful. I will test and let you know!! Thanks

Comment: Also coming from the `OOPs` background its really hard to get your head around this functional paradigm. You see that `return` method on the first line of the method call. I am, however, loving this new paradigm.